# Android Circle Shape in 16 to 23 Android Version

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make a circle that is perfect in all Android versions.

I tried to create a drawable like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
...color..stroke...
</shape>
```

And in my layout, I created a TextView like:

```
<TextView
    android:background="@drawable/shape_circle"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
/>
```

The problem is that is some devices shows a circle view, and some others shows a oval view.

1. Moto G2 - 5.0.2 = Circle
2. Samsung S2 - API 16 = Oval
3. Samsung S3 - API 18 = Circle
4. Samsung S3 - API 16 = Oval
5. Nexus 5 - API 22 = Circle

EDIT:
**layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_table_empty"
        android:text="14"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/medium_gray"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_table"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_table_used"
        android:text="14"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_table_used"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/text_table_num_orders"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/text_table_used"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/text_table_used"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/light_green"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**drawable shape_table:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/light_gray"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/medium_gray"
        />
    <size
        android:width="64dp"
        android:height="64dp"/>
</shape>
```

**OBS:** The drawable *shape_table_used* is the same as *shape_table*, without stroke and other color.

Comment: Please add your whole layout file where you are using your textview

Comment: I added in my last edition.

Comment: remove size tag from drawable

Comment: My suggestion to you is to draw a circle in custom view. It will be in circle shape on every device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use this
 you can also remove the size tag but in this case your view hight and width must be  equal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#E0D8D0" />

    <size
        android:width="80dp"
        android:height="80dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you almost get it right. A circle is an oval with with same width and height so you can just set the width and height inside the shape and you will get circle in every device

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="@color/white"/>

    <size
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="100dp"/>
</shape>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if You want a  circle You use this but your View hight and width must be equal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
        android:startColor="#FFFF0000" />

</shape>
```

and You also use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
        android:startColor="#FFFF0000" />
    <size
        android:width="80dp"
        android:height="80dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Please see another answer bellow